# Sphinx rst2pdf: Numbering figures

Tags: python-sphinx, rst2pdf

I have some documents on Sphinx 2.x. In addition to an HTML version (`make html`), I want to export it in a PDF version as well, preferably using **rst2pdf**:

My documents have some figure images. Here's a snippet in `index.rst`.

```
.. figure:: ./_images/img01.png

   Caption for img01.


.. figure:: ./_images/img02.png

   Caption for img02.
```

I want to add *"Figure <#>"* in the beginning of every caption.  Does anyone have any thoughts? Please note

- **numfig** doesn't work with rst2pdf.

*Update (3/22/2020).* Add the following lines in `conf.py`.

```
numfig = True

numfig_format = {
    'figure': 'Figure %s.'
    }

numfig_secnum_depth = 1
```

In the HTML output it works.

[image: HTML output with numfig]

In the rst2PDF version, you don't see *"Figure #"*.

[image: rst2PDF output with the same numfig configuration]

- The **:counter:** directive doesn't work with Sphinx; I get the following error:

```
.. figure:: ./_images/img01.png

   Figure :counter:`figure`. Caption for img01.
```

```
$ sphinx-build -b pdf ./source/ ./build/
Running Sphinx v2.4.4
/home/sarah/sphinx_test/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py:126: RemovedInSphinx30Warning: sphinx.environment.NoUri is deprecated.
Check CHANGES for Sphinx API modifications.
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Initiated sphinxcontrib-images backend: `sphinxcontrib_images_lightbox2.lightbox2:LightBox2`
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [pdf]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index

Exception occurred:
  File "/home/sarah/sphinx_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docutils/nodes.py", line 439, in copy
    return self.__class__(reprunicode(self), rawsource=self.rawsource)
AttributeError: 'CounterNode' object has no attribute 'rawsource'
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-1bzghsm6.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of [`numfig`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-numfig) and [`numfig_format`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-numfig_format) for proper syntax and usage.

Comment: Please search _"numfig"_ with the updated question above (I added the numfig results).

Comment: Sphinx can generate PDF.

Comment: You meant I should generate PDF via XeLaTeX? (I don't think Sphinx can generate PDF  directly.)

Comment: That is correct, or try the rinoh builder. Details: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.latex.latexbuilder